# Ember pushObjects() not notifying computed property

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying to use `ember-light-table` and I'm having some troubles on updating my array of objects.

When I use the action `updateList()`, I can see both arrays changing (adding/removing objects to the list), but the computed property `tableModel` is not triggered!

I thought `pushObjects()` would do the trick, but it's not notifying for some reason (it's adding). I also tried to initialize select_people with `Ember.A()`, although `[]` should already be an ember array...

My mixin:

```
// table-testing
import Ember from 'ember';
import Table from 'ember-light-table';

export default Ember.Mixin.create({
  table: null,
  tableColumns: null,
  tableModel: null,
  init() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    let table = new Table(this.get('tableColumns'), this.get('tableModel'), { enableSync: this.get('enableSync') });
    this.set('table', table);
  }
});
```

My controller

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import TableTesting from '../mixins/table-testing';
const { computed } = Ember;

export default Ember.Controller.extend(TableTesting, {
  tableColumns: computed(function() {
    return [{
      label: 'First Name',
      valuePath: 'firstName',
      width: '50%',
      sortable: false,
    }, {
      label: 'Last Name'
      valuePath: 'lastName',
      width: '50%'
    }]
  }),
  tableModel: computed('selected_people.@each.firstName', function() {
    // THIS MESSAGE ONLY SHOW WHEN VIEW IS RENDERED
    // I've tried .[], .@each, .length... none of them worked and I believe @each.firstName would be the most appropriated from what I've read
    console.log('computed method not showing',this.get('selected_people'));
    return this.get('selected_people');
  }),
  init() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    this.set('selected_people',[]);
  },
  actions: {
    updateList(item, moveToList) {
      let removeFromList, fromList, toList;
      if (moveToList === 'people') {
        removeFromList = 'selected_people'
      } else if (moveToList === "selected_people") {
        removeFromList = 'people';
      }
      // get the object lists
      fromList = this.get(removeFromList);
      toList = this.get(moveToList);
      // update list ---> HERE I UPDATE USING KOVL METHOD
      toList.pushObjects(item);
      fromList.removeObjects(item);
      console.log('update!',this.get('selected_people'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code looks perfect to me. if you can reproduce it in twiddle it will help us to look into what is going on. Just make sure `tableModel` should be accessed/required by the template after `updateList` function called. You might be accessed `tableModel` property inside the `if` block which might be false or not rendering the particular block means it will not execute the computed property.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `pushObject` and `removeObject`, singular?

Comment: @kumkanillam, I will try to reproduce in the twiddle. I don't use tableModel anywhere else. I use the object table created in the mixin which uses this.get('tableModel')... maybe this is the catch!

Comment: @locks, those method exist. You use array of objects rather than one object You can check the API [here](https://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.MutableArray.html#method_pushObjects)

Comment: I put on my template one iteration over modelTable and it didn't help... I'll see if I can do something over twiddle

Comment: My twiddle is working... ugh...

Comment: @kumkanillam, thanks a lot. From your answer I found out the problem. The enablesync variable was undefined, so the table object was not checking the `tableModel` property, thus not checking in the template. When the variable is not used in the template the computed property doesn't work (I didn't know that it had to be used there... thanks!) So if you post this answer I'll gladly accept it ;)

Comment: I am aware the API exists, but your code implies that `item` isn't an array, hence the suggestion.

Comment: Ok, sorry it wasn't clear. It's because `updateList()` is passed to a component and when used there the item passed is always one array. Thanks for thinking of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make sure `tableModel` should be accessed/required by the template or in code.

Computed property is lazy, so it will be calculated when you ask for it either inside the code or in a template. otherwise, it will not be called. 
First time when we call, it will return result and it will be cached. and subsequent access will get it from cache. Changing any of the dependent properties causes the cache to invalidate so that the computed function runs again on the next access.

Mostlty copied from [guides.emberjs](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.13.0/object-model/computed-properties/#toc_computed-properties-in-action)

Comment: Feel free to update my answer with your specific research and how you solved it...You are the one who nailed it